# UIImageView performance

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, frame-rate

I have an iphone app that gets jpeg images through wifi at a rate I can control and displayes them using a uiimageview. it seems that the best performance i can get is about 2fps. it lookes like the uiimageview cant handle [uiimageview setimage:image] quickly.

is there a better solution other than using uiimageview that will allow me a betterframe rate?

Comment: I don't thing UIImageView is the cause here.  How do you handle image transfer accross the network and how big are you jpgs ?

Comment: @VdesmedT the jpegs are transfered using a get request from a .net server and are in json format. the size is about 30Kb.

Comment: JSon format ? Like { name  : "MyImage.jpg",  bytes : [1,2,3, ... ]} ?

Comment: @VdesmedT exactly! is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you need JSon to pass multiple info from your service but clearly re creating your image from a json string consumes both memory and processor time.  Use the Json to pass the url of the bytes instead and retrieve the bytes using another get.

I expect you to have a json like { path = "/images/funnryrabbits.jpg", anyProperty: "anyValue" }

Comment: so i will create the image from that path and set it as the uiimageview image?

Comment: for example.  Another approach would be to pass multiple images path in your Json and the just changes the image property of your UIImageView each time an image is downloaded.

Comment: I only have one image at a time. but thanks! your previous advice helped. i am now up to 7FPS which is not bad for what we need here!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.animationImages` property of UIImageView. It takes an array of UIImages and animates them like a flipbook or an animated gif. You can make some cheap but quick animations by putting in a bunch of slides and letting UIImageView do the animation.

I don't know if you can manipulate that array as it's rendering the animation, is the thing.

Comment: I think he wants the animation to run on the fly with the image coming from the network.

Comment: Is the point that you want them to animate quickly? Or as they download?

Comment: @Dan Ray I dont want them to animate. I want to be able to switch the viewd image at a fast rate.

Comment: @Amit - What's the difference?

Comment: @Dan Ray only the last image counts (it's live)